# twitter bootstrap modal and tabbed navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have modal that opens up and in that modal i want to show tabbed navigation. i have the following code

```
<div id="TaskListDialog" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="windowTitleLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Task List</h3>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        Data 1
    </div>
           <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
<p>Data 2.</p>
</div>
</div>
        </div>
   </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="CloseTaskList();">Close</a>
        </div>
   </div>
```

the problem i have is that modal launches with the first tab but on clicking the second tab nothing happens.

what have i missed that it's not loading the second tab.

any help highly appreciated.

Comment: What browser are you using? How is the modal being launched? Your modal code seems to work fine here - http://bootply.com/61902

Comment: the modal is being launched as follows ....function ShowTasks() {
            $('#TaskListDialog').modal('show');
        }

Comment: i have tested this on IE10 and Chrome and it does not work, surprisingly the link you sent works on both the browsers

Comment: ok, i got it to work, it was that the tab.js file was not loading early enough. moving it to the head section before the modal works fine.